# How can'i pass this " openssh-client' has no installation candidate "

Tags: server, apt, package-management, ssh, openssh

I am trying to use `ssh` command, but I have this:

```
sudo ssh git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[sudo] password for dali: 
sudo: ssh: command not found
```

So when i am trying to install `openssh-client`, I have this :

```
dali@dali-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-client
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Package openssh-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openssh-client' has no installation candidate
```

same as when I remove it and reinstall it.

Comment: Could you specify what's the Ubuntu version you're using?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` first, it might be that the repositories are out of date

Comment: i try it but can't help

Comment: What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=C lsb_release -a` and `sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get update && sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get install openssh-client`? (`LC_MESSAGES=C` renders the messages in the program output English.)

Comment: this is the output of ** LC_MESSAGES=C lsb_release -a** :  `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.10
Release: 15.10
Codename: wily
  ` . ANd * sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get update && sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get install openssh-client * : `sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get update && sudo LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get install openssh-client
Package openssh-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is from another source

E: Package 'openssh-client' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't say which operating system version you use, so I would first try to search for it, giving different package names, like ssh, ssh AND client etc etc.

Open Terminal windows and try make few searches and check whether package description says about ssh/ssh client.

> sudo apt-cache search XXX

...where XXX is one of the following: openssh, ssh, ssh-client

IF it does, then install this package with:

> sudo apt-get install  _package_name_received_

Eventually, search for this file on disk, as you might have it stored in different location, and if found, use absolute path to this ssh file.

> sudo find / -name ssh -type f 2>/dev/null

Comment: Instead of the Find, I suggest to ask to DPKG : dpkg -l | grep ssh

Comment: i can't find it in my files

Comment: Then you probably don't have any repo with packages. Could you show us what's inside this file: 
/etc/apt/sources.list  
...and all files inside folder: 
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d  ?   

I suspect they are missing or empty...

Comment: well this is what in /etc/apt/sources.list :

"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily universe"

. And this is the contain of /etc/apt/sources.list.d :

"dali@dali-Lenovo-G50-70:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 avril 13 12:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 avril 12 10:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 avril 13 12:25 elasticsearch-1.7.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  152 avril 12 10:31 webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-3-wily.list"

Comment: Good, now you have to do THREE things. First, comment all lines in files from sources.list.d/ folder - to make sure....  Next, remove everything from /etc/apt/sources.list and add there these two lines. Remove quotes of course. First line: "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main multiverse universe restricted"  and second line:  "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main multiverse universe restricted".  The thirs thing is to execute from terminal "sudo apt-get update"  and fourth step is to search for ssh package and install it, like "sudo apt-get install openssh-client"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your repo list and reinstall openssh-client again.

```
$apt-get update
$apt-get install openssh-client
```